# Control height BoxDecoration

Tags: flutter, dart

I got stuck to control height BoxDecoration. It using a lot of space. I've add height under `Container` still cannot fix it.
You can refer this image bellow.

[image]

Bellow is my issue code:

```
return AlertDialog(
    insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 320),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)),
    title: Container(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 253, 253),
        child: Text('Comment', style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 4, 4))),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(17),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    ),
    titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: < Widget > [
                SizedBox(
                    width: 450,
                    height: 570,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 1,
                            ),
                            itemCount: commentList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                                        child: Container(
                                            child: InkWell(
                                                // height: 10,
                                                child: Container(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, top: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                                        border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffD4D4D4), width: 2.0)),
                                                    child: Column(
                                                        children: < Widget > [
                                                            Container(
                                                                child: Row(
                                                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                                    children: [
                                                                        Text(
                                                                            "testor: Lim",
                                                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                                        ),
                                                                        // Spacer(),
                                                                        Text(
                                                                            DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy')
                                                                            .format(DateTime.parse(commentList[index].createdAt))
                                                                            .toString() +
                                                                            '(' +
                                                                            DateFormat('HH:mm')
                                                                            .format(DateTime.parse(commentList[index].createdAt))
                                                                            .toString() +
                                                                            ')',
                                                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.blue),
                                                                        )
                                                                    ],
                                                                ),
                                                            ),
                                                            Container(
                                                                child: Column(
                                                                    children: [
                                                                        Text(
                                                                            "important",
                                                                            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                                                        ),
                                                                    ],
                                                                ),
                                                            ),
                                                        ],
                                                    )),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                );
                            },
                    ),
                ),
            ])),
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 1,
              childAspectRatio: 5,
            ),
```

Because, to manage the size of `Gridview` items, you have to use `childAspectRatio`.

Try different ratios till you achieve your preferred look. You can also calculate this ratio using screen size and item size.